# Alternative to using multiple criteria in COUNT(DISTINCT()) or "Error: could not identify an equality operator for type record"

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, distinct

Our vendor recently moved to AWS's Redshift which doesn't appear to allow multiple criteria in a COUNT(DISTINCT()) query.

I'm trying to count up all visits made by users in a year, but it's possible that users might have duplicate visits on a single day, which I want to avoid counting.

Using this code, I'm hoping to get a table of the number of visits per year, removing duplicate visits on the same day.

```
SELECT DATE_PART_YEAR(visit_date) as "year", COUNT(DISTINCT(userID, visit_date))
FROM visits
GROUP BY DATE_PART_YEAR(visit_date)
ORDER BY year;
```

Expected Result:

| year | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2018 | 12,703 |
| 2019 | 14,058 |
| 2020 | 15,920 |
| 2021 | 25,024 |
| 2022 | 39,739 |

This code worked on the previous database, but now throws an error I haven't been able to solve:

```
ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type record [ErrorId: 1-64c01a9a-51cd1ea7119c39603889c9c4]
```

I've confirmed that the query runs fine when it's only COUNT(DISTINCT(userID)), but as soon as I change it to COUNT(DISTINCT(userID, visit_date)), it throws the above error.

I've been unable to decipher the error online and since it worked fine on the old server (AWS's Athena), I'm assuming it's specific to Redshift (which also required DATE_PART_YEAR(), instead of just YEAR()).

Is there a way to work around using multiple criteria in COUNT(DISTINCT()) so that I can count up all the days users had visits?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a subquery for this purpose?

```
SELECT "year", userID, count(*) as count
from (
    SELECT v.DATE_PART_YEAR(visit_date) as "year", v.userID, v.visit_date
    FROM visits v
    GROUP BY DATE_PART_YEAR(visit_date), userID, visit_date
) t
GROUP BY "year", userID
ORDER BY year, userID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The value you are performing DISTINCT on is "userID, visit_date" which is being seen as a RECORD data type and Redshift doesn't know how equality is defined for this type.  The simplest way to concatenate these values into a single string and then DISTINCT will know what to do.

Try:

```
SELECT DATE_PART_YEAR(visit_date) as "year", COUNT(DISTINCT(userID::text || visit_date::text))
FROM visits
GROUP BY DATE_PART_YEAR(visit_date)
ORDER BY year;
```